# MVC 5 With Tinymce Editor Contain Words "FIND", "SERVICES" and some more around 8 more letter "ERR_CONNECTION_RESET"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, post, replace, find, tinymce

recently i am facing problem on my all MVC applications using TinyMce editor i am using that editor to allow users to input content of the page, strange things is happening now. when ever they have type following word in content.
"find", "services","replace" and some 8 more character inside editor, and when we hit safe button immediately after server giving me following error.

This webpage is not available

ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

as far for me this is Firewall problem. but i need to know if someone have same problem how can we explain network people?

Comment: No need to add question in all caps

Answer (score -1):

The error clearly indicates as you mentioned that this is an internet problem as it suggests webpage is not available. There is a [video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9orMZyky-UI) that indicates you may need to reset somethings on your network. Checkout if that helps.

Comment: as i said site is working and this problem only come when i type defined word like"find" ,"services","replace" if i do not use these words in tinymce editor every thing work .. i m 100% sure this is firewall issue just finding someone who have same problem.